# How do I create a hover drop down menu that has space between the hover item and drop down elements without the hover effect getting disabled?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have an item in my navbar that has a hover effect - however there should be spacing between the items that appear on hover and the hovered element. But if I add spacing, the hover effect will become disabled in the white space so the links in the drop down content cannot be clicked. How can I fix this so that the white space in between keeps the hover effect on?

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-header">
  <div class="dropdown-nav">
    <div class="icon-container">
      <a class="navbar-text" href="">Content 1</a>
      <img class="arrow" src="./arrow.png" alt="menu arrow" />
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-nav-content">
      <p>Content 1</p>
      <p>Content 3</p>
      <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-text" href="">Content 2</a>
  <a class="navbar-text" href="">Content 3</a>
  <a class="navbar-text" href="">Content 4</a>
  <a class="navbar-text" href="">Content 5</a>
  <a class="navbar-text" href="">Content 6</a>
</nav>
```

and here is my CSS/SCSS:

```
.nav-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  .navbar-text {
    color: #9f9f9f;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .icon-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

.dropdown-nav {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-nav-content {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 240px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 85px;
}

.dropdown-nav:hover .dropdown-nav-content {
  display: flex;
}
```

The dropdown-nav-content is positioned top: 85px to give it spacing between the hovered element - however the white space between them will unhover it. If I attempt to add bottom padding to the "Content 1" it displaces the element out of alignment.

Comment: Add some transparent :before element so it covers the white space and soes not allow hover out when you move pointer to dropdown.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to implement that - could you give me a short snippet? The :before element should go on the .dropdown-nav right?

Comment: to .dropdown-nav-content, make it overlap the white space so pointer is always over .dropdowm-nav-content

Comment: I see, that works but the problem is the background color of the dropdown-nav-content gets stretched all the way up to the hovered menu item

Comment: Provide some working example so i will be able to help, it's hard to say wothout working code.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it with your advice! .dropdown-nav-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -85px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
} - thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css file.

```
.dropdown-nav-content::before {
  display:block;
  content:'';
  height:20px;
}
```

The `::before` is added by your browser "before" the element: in this case before each element with the class `.dropdown-nav-content`.

Be aware that you must define a `content` attribute in order for your browser to create it.
Set the content to `''` to make it empty.

Set the `height` to the one you need.

Hope this help ;)